# Getting a random double value between -1 and 1

Tags: java, random

I'm creating a Neural Network in Java and need to create a method to generate random weights initially.

I need to create a function that returns a random double value between -1 and 1 but not sure of the logic for doing this so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it inclusive or exclusive at the ends of the range? Or different at both ends? You should always specify that when you're talking about ranges. The answers you have to date include -1 but exclude 1.

Comment: ...because Math.random() returns a double value with a positive sign, *greater than or equal* to 0.0 and *less than* 1.0. Which I didn't know until about 30 seconds ago...

Comment: @pax When dealing with a real interval, the endpoints will [almost surely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) never be picked anyway.  When instead dealing with floating-point intervals, the probability of randomly selecting an endpoint is only slightly higher.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan, that's correct for the upper endpoint but not the lower, `nextInt()` and its brethren will often return zero - well, about as often as expected :-) I was just stating that it's important to know the desired behaviour at both endpoints (in the question) and the actual behaviour (in the answers).

Comment: @Michael Personally I'd usually include the lower, but exclude the higher bound - and I don't see any good reason to change that for floats? (ok it's unlikely that `higher bound == lower bound of next element` will be useful for floats, but why use two different conventions?)

Comment: @DNA No, this is not an **exact** duplicate.  That question covers *integers*, not *doubles*.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28) class's nextDouble() method.

```
Random rng = new Random();
// to get a double between -1 and 1
return rng.nextDouble() * 2 - 1; // rng.nextDouble() is between 0 and 1
```

Comment: And, unless I'm missing something, `SplittableRandom().nextDouble(-1, 1 + Double.MIN_VALUE)` should give you double between -1 and 1 (including both)

Comment: @Joschua you would probably need Math.nextUp, not + Double.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't that result in same? `Math.nextUp` returns the floating-point value adjacent to d in the direction of positive infinity. (from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp\(double\))). And that should be `d + MIN_VALUE` AFAICS. It also mentions "If the argument is zero, the result is Double.MIN_VALUE". Maybe `nextUp` is cleaner though.

Comment: @Joschua d + MIN_VALUE is only the next higher number from d if d is sufficiently small; otherwise d + MIN_VALUE == d. Math.nextUp(d) == d + Math.ulp(d), though.

Comment: Oh.. wow. I guess I didn't know as much about floating point numbers as I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

[Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) will give you a random double between 0 and 1.  You can multiply that result by 2 and subtract 1 for a random double between -1 and 1.

Alternatively you can apply the same transformation to a call to the [nextDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) method from `java.util.Random`, but this requires an explicit instance of `Random` whereas that is done behind the scenes with `Math.random()`.